# Jsf custom converter life cyle

Tags: jsf-2, converters

From [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152579/jsf-displaying-entities-with-ids-how-to-translate-ids-to-descriptions) on this site I realized I don't know anything about custom converter life cycle. I searched a bit on internet and found nothing useful.

I would like to understand if custom converters are created once for all and recycled any time they are needed or if they are created on the fly and destroyed.

I suppose their main purpose is to perform some easy and light tasks, so it would make no difference if the a new instance of the converter is created each time it is found inside a jsf page sent to the user.

But I would like to use a custom converter to solve a common task in what it is an unpaved way. My custom convert would have an heavy initialization logic, so I have to be sure about its life-cycle. It must be created once for all and not every time it is needed. Is it possible ?

Depending on the answers I will receive I can abort the idea of using custom converter or decide to move the heavy initialization logic in a singletone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converters are created once for each time you reference them when using [`@FacesConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/FacesConverter.html) annotation. That means if you execute slow code there it'll bring you into problems.

Alternatively, you can annotate them as `@ManagedBean` with the scope you want and use them with an [EL reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) instead of raw converter id. If you want to initialize them in some way, the solution for you would be setting them the scope for the whole application and making them eagerly initialized, so they'll be created when application starts up:

**Converter:**

```
@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class WorkerConverter implements Converter {

    public WorkerConverter() {
        System.out.println("Building converter...");
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            String value) {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(value);
        if (id == 1) {
            return new Worker(1, "John");
        } else {
            return new Worker(1, "Larry");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        return ((Worker) value).getId().toString();
    }

}
```

**Managed bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SelectWorkerBean {

    public static class Worker {
        Integer id;
        String name;

        public Worker(Integer id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Worker other = (Worker) obj;
            if (id == null) {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Worker [name=" + name + "]";
        }

    }

    private Worker selectedWorker;

    private List<Worker> workers = Arrays.asList(new Worker(1, "John"),
            new Worker(2, "Larry"));

    public Worker getSelectedWorker() {
        return selectedWorker;
    }

    public List<Worker> getWorkers() {
        return workers;
    }

    public void send() {
        System.out.println(selectedWorker + " selected");
    }

    public void setSelectedWorker(Worker selectedWorker) {
        this.selectedWorker = selectedWorker;
    }

}
```

**Page:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Test page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectWorkerBean.selectedWorker}"
            converter="#{workerConverter}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{selectWorkerBean.workers}" var="worker"
                itemLabel="#{worker.name}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:commandButton value="send" action="#{selectWorkerBean.send}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```